# Eclipse Plugin project with other project dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dependencies

I have an Eclipse plugin project, and it depends on other projects that I have in my Eclipse workspace. After adding the project dependencies under "Java Build Path" -> "Projects" tab, and also selecting the project in the "Order and Export" I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

I'm assuming that the other projects have not been properly included into the plugin. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An Eclipse plug in project manages dependencies differently than a regular Java project.

I'm assuming that you're adding packages with .class files.

Define a library folder in your Eclipse plug-in project.  Copy any external classes and/or jars to the library folder.

Open up the MANIFEST.MF file under the META-INF directory.  You'll see a formatted editor with 8 tabs on the bottom.

Click on the Runtime tab.  Add the external classes and/or jars in the library folder to the Classpath.  This will also add these external classes and or jars to the Java Build Path of the project.

Click on the Dependencies tab, and add the other Java projects in the Imported Packages dialog.  You have to check the box labeled "Show non-exported packages".  If your other Java projects are Eclipse plug ins, add them under Required Plug-ins instead.

Comment: I tried adding packages in the "Imported Packages" section, but I can't find the packages in my other project in the "Package Selection" dialog. Is there something I need to do before this?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I've created a new Eclipse plug in project.  I've updated my answer with more instructions.

Comment: Gilbert: Could you please clarify your instructions a bit? I added the binaries via Project -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Class folder and then imported the packages on the plugin's Dependencies tab. I'm now getting "No available bundle exports package 'x'" errors for the packages I imported in the Manifest.MF file. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Todd:  You caught me on the day I'm switching computers.  I should have my Eclipse work spaces functional in another day or so.  It sounds like what you did should work.

Comment: @Gilbert: thank you for the quick response. It seems that you can't add folders from another project in the workspace to the plugin's classpath (using the runtime tab) since it the dialog is rooted in the plugin's project folder. On a related note, what do you mean by "add the external classes" to the classpath? I'm reading it as: add the bin output folder for the other project to the classpath. This interpretation may just be wishful thinking, though. I'm using Eclipse Helios SR1.

Comment: @Todd:  You're correct.  I've updated my answer again.  You have to copy the external classes and / or jars to a folder inside the plugin's project folder.

Comment: @Gilbert: I found that I could link to the "external folder" by going to the Build tab and selecting Add Folder -> Create New Folder -> Advanced. This has worked well so far...

Answer (score 0):

In case if you're not in a position to copy the dependent project into your plugin project and you are sure about the presence of the dependent project in the target eclipse where plugin is to be installed, then you can either use 
`Runtime.exec()`  to run the Java class you want to run or `ProcessBuilder` class to run the class.

Like this:

```
// To compile
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac yourclass.java"); 
// To execute
Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java yourclass");
```

This may be considered in the worst case.
I had such an experience and hence thought some may find it useful.