# Add a project to a plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, dependencies

I have a ordinary java project (P1). The project uses another java project (P2) which is added to the build path of P1. I create this dependency as I need to change both projects. I want if I change P2 then see changes in P1.

I recently convert my project as a plugin. However, when I run the program it can not find the second project, and shows **NoClassDefFoundError** compiler error while from class path file I can see the project is added in class path.

```
classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/P2"/
```

I know how to create a jar file from P2 and add that to the plugin (it can solve my problem), but I do not know how to add another eclipse project (as source code) to a plugin. As I said I want to change P2 as well and it is difficult to create a jar file from P2 after each change and add that to the plugin.

Please let me know how can I add a source project to a plugin.
Is it possible to do that? I also read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869693/eclipse-plugin-project-with-other-project-dependencies?rq=1), but could not help me.

Comment: Did you try Maven or any other dependency mgmt tool?

Comment: I am not familiar with Maven, but if it can help please let me know then I can try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting the second project to a plugin project and add it in the manifest of the first(**Dependencies>Required Plugins**).