# How to have multi-level dependencies in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In my java project I have a library I am working on and a second project that has the first project as a dependency. The first project has a library as a dependency in the form of a jar file. When I run the second project, I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for one of the classes of the jar file. When I move the src for the second project into the first project, it runs without errors. I've added the jar library to the export tab on the first project but the problem persists. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869693/eclipse-plugin-project-with-other-project-dependencies)? Make sure you also have setup the proper Eclipse Plugin dependency from your second to your first project. Assuming that you work with Eclipse Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Add the first project to the Java build path of the second project:

Select the second project and in ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path***, in the ***Projects*** tab click ***Add...*** and select the first project.